# XML Schema validator for key / keyref

Tags: xml, schema, key, validation, keyref

Is there an online XML validator that reports errors for key and keyref violations?

From my trying, with [corefiling](http://www.corefiling.com/opensource/schemaValidate.html) for example, it does not work. It seems to me that it just ignores the key and keyref specifications.

What I want is to validate an XML instance against a Schema and get errors if
- there are duplicate keys
- keyrefs are not referencing existing elements

Comment: just in case, you need an online solution, basically go to a website and paste your XML to validate it, not solve it programmatically? it would be more in spirit of the SO if you asked how to build a service like that :)

Comment: My first guess would be that your schema is wrong rather than the online validator being wrong, unless you can provide evidence to the contrary. Have you tried it using any other schema validators?

Comment: The thing is, I get no errors even if I put invalid key / keyref values into my xml instance.